# Ubuntu touch phone does uNav app use UK postcodes?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, phone

Should the uNav app on Touch accept UK postcodes?
UK postcodes are not recognised when I type them into the search bar, it sometimes tries to send me to France!
I am using the stable channel on a Nexus 4.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that you are able to enter the initial part of the postcode you want in the search bar and you can go to the rough area. However, it does not seem to want to then narrow down the search when you add the remaining part of the post code. For this reason I also use Here Maps, from the Ubuntu store. With here maps you can search by the full postcode.